# How to pass class variable from one script to another

Tags: python, import, tkinter, filepath

I am looking to take the filepath that is captured when the user selects the file using tkFileDialog and pass it to another script that can open that file and execute another script. The end goal here is to select two xml files and compare them. The external script will be triggered by the confirm button and will output any differences found between the two files in the text frame.

```
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        path1 = StringVar()
        path2 = StringVar()

        master.title("XML Compare Tool")
        master.geometry('700x300')

        self.bb1 = Button(master, text="Browse", command=lambda: path1.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()))
        self.bb1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.bb2 = Button(master, text="Browse", command=lambda: path2.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()))
        self.bb2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.confirm = Button(master, text="Confirm", command='')
        self.confirm.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='')

        self.entry1 = Entry(master, width=75, textvariable=path1)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

        self.entry2 = Entry(master, width=75, textvariable=path2)
        self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.t_label = Label(master, text="Script Output")
        self.t_label.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='')

        self.t_frame = Frame(master, bg="white", height=150, width=600)
        #self.t_frame.place(x=25, y=120, height=250, width=690)
        self.t_frame.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='')
        self.t_text = Text(self.t_frame)
        #self.t_text.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

root = Tk()
my_gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since you are just learning, I recommend avoiding `lambda` unless it's truly necessary. Your buttons should call proper functions / methods. It makes coding much easier, _especially_ if you are just now learning how to program.

Comment: if external script is python script and it has code organized in functions then you can import this script and call function.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is actually passing arguments to a tkinter callback. Does [this](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) help?

Comment: This is not a very good answer. Please read some of the answers to this question: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)